# User Interactive Service in Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, service, console, winlogon

We have developed a network based C++ application that should run as a service for Windows XP, 7 32-bit system.

- The application is console based.
- User should be able to see the logs in console once the app is up and running.

To make application run as a service , we used [XYNTService](https://github.com/mikeowens/XYNTService)

The application is working as a service and it works fine under XP.

But I am not able to see the console under Windows 7, Since the service is running under the local SERVICE account, probably we can not see the GUI or access it in any way, because it is running in another winlogon session.

**So can some one please suggest how can we make the service interactive so that user can see logs on the console while the app is running as a service?**

Else
What if I make it a tray based application, is there a way to redirect logs a window?

Comment: I would not go down that road since on Vista and above Interactive Services are ugly.  Their UI is shown on a completely separate desktop (or Window Station?  I forget) and switching back and forth is cumbersome.  A proper reworking of the application would be much more preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can subscribe to logon/logoff events and then use [WTSEnumerateSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833.aspx) with [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429.aspx) to create GUI each time user logs into system, however it's not a good choice.

Making a tray app that automatically runs when user logs into system is better idea, you can use any of IPC mechanisms (named pipes, shared memory, sockets) to sent logs from service to tray app.